# Проблема с regex и кодировкой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый вечере, имеется Ппроблема с regex и кодировкой файлов
Имеется php скрипт

```
<?
# Если не передан параметр
if (!defined('UF_AUTOLOADER_SETUP')) die(header('Location: /404/'));
# Переменные
$message = urldecode($project['text']);
# Проверка
if(!preg_match('/^[^\.][0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁА\s\-\.\,\_\!\?\(\)]+[^\.]/', $message)) die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '024')));
# Проверка
if(empty($project['id']) || empty($message) || empty($project['captcha'])) die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '004', 'critical' => true)));
# Проверка на пустоту.
$message = trim($message);
if(!empty($message)){
    # Замена [br/]
    $test = str_replace('[br/]', '', $message);
    $message = str_replace('[br/]', '%BR%', $message);
    # Проверка
    if($test == '') die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '024')));
    # Парсим пустые BB коды
    $confing = new confing();
    if($confing->parser($message, 'check') == 0){
        # Проверки на пустоту.
        if($confing->parser($message, 'remove') == '') die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '024')));
    # Пустые BB Коды
    } else die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '024')));
    # Замена %BR%
    $message = str_replace('%BR%', '[br/]', $message);
    # Добавляем комментарий
    $add = $db->insert("INSERT INTO `umbrella_forum_messages` (`uid`, `tid`, `fid`, `message`, `time`, `tm`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Array($_SESSION['id'], $project['id'], $topic['fid'], htmlspecialchars($message), date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 't'));
    # Ответ
    die(json_encode(Array('request' => 'forum', 'type' => 'newmessage', 'status' => true, 'mid' => intval($add), 'id' => intval($project['id']), 'overpage' => $page)));
} else die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '024')));
```

Самое сообщение передаётся через js (json формат), кодировка в JS файле - UTF-8, кодировка php файла - windows-1251, при отправке сообщения, мне выдаёт ошибку

```
if(!preg_match('/^[^\.][0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁА\s\-\.\,\_\!\?\(\)]+[^\.]/', $message)) die(json_encode(Array('type' => 'error', 'errid' => '024')));
```

Пытался экранировать кодировку:

```
$message = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", urldecode($project['text']));
```

В итоге, все русские символы просто исчезали и в базу шло пустое сообщение... Что конкретно я делаю не так или в чём ошибка php кода?

Comment: На дворе 2016 год, а вы все еще работаете с 1251? P.S. Что вы хотите проверить этим условием `if(!preg_match('/^[^\.][0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁА\s\-\.\,\_\!\?\(\)]+[^\.]/', $message))`?

Comment: Да знаю что, utf-8 использовать сейчас актуально... preg_match я пытаюсь проверить текст, чтобы в тексте не было левых символов, чтобы тупо не написали пробеллами или не юзали ком-цию alt + 0160...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что preg_match, как и preg_match_all работают в unix/linux режиме и используют utf-8 (как правило).
Так или иначе, ваша проверка - это жесть =)))

Я затрудняюсь понять, что именно вы проверяете этим выражением `if(!preg_match('/^[^\.][0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁА\s\-\.\,\_\!\?\(\)]+[^\.]/', $message))`

Но попробуйте так:

if(!preg_match('/^[^.][\w\s-.\,!\?()]+[^.]/iu', $message))

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам, Станислав. Помогло!